# Will deleting my “/usr/local/” in macOS folder be a good start for a clean Python reinstall?

Tags: macos, python

I am using macOS and have had trouble trying to install a Python package recently (SpiceyPy), I was lost in all the stuff that I had installed since I started using python.

I did not really understand what I was doing when installing stuff (I still don't fully understand) and I suspect that I made a mess: I have `brew`, Homebrew, `easy_install`, `pip`, `pip2`, `pip2.7`, etc... in my `/usr/local/bin` folder.

So now I would like to clear everything that I installed by using python, have a fresh start and do things more orderly this time.

Would deleting my entire `/usr/local/` folder be a good start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuking *`/usr/local`* can lead to unpredictable results if you have other software that has been installed there.

To clean up Homebrew see this [article](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/clean-install-of-homebrew/661)

I'd recommend rebuilding this way as opposed to just nuking *`/usr/local`*.

Net is:

> - brew bundle dump
> - Review this link on Git https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall
> - brew bundle